# How do I manage SAS formats from various sources?

Tags: sas, maintainability, formats

I am wondering how I can efficiently manage formats in SAS for a reporting office that takes in data from various sources, some with proper lookup tables / metadata, and some without.

For data sources that have proper metadata, joining tables for value descriptions works fine, but when metadata doesn't exist and needs to be maintained separately, how should that be done? Some straightforward examples/ideas:

- Plain `.sas` files with a native `PROC FORMAT` step that is maintained separately.
- External files (e.g., Excel, CSV) that are maintained separately and imported into SAS to create a format library.
- Database tables maintained separately that can be read from to create a format library.

In addition to just the formatted values, managing value changes (i.e., effective dates for certian values) is also a concern.

Any help in conventions or standards that work well for this type of task is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a single best solution here - it depends largely on your environment, your users, etc.

If you have fairly naive users, then I'd definitely recommend a single complete repository if possible; whether that is a .sas7bcat file if you are using a single SAS version/OS/bitness, or a ready-made table/dataset to input into PROC FORMAT (and a .sas file included in their autoexec to do the importing).  The biggest drawbacks to this are that you have to manage it actively (you cannot allow users to write their own formats to the master format dataset, for example, as they may overwrite other ones), and that there will be additional work to ensure format names do not conflict - `YNF.` might be `1=YES 2=NO` or `1=YES 0=NO` or something else.  This also doesn't allow you to very easily handle effective dates; but it's possible this is better for your users (and then just handle the documentation separately).

If you have more advanced users, then you might consider a table/dataset that is more relational in nature.  A hybrid approach might include a dataset with columns:

1. Dataset Name (qualified as needed to ensure uniqueness)
2. Format Name
3. Start
4. Label
5. Other elements (Type, HLO, etc.)
6. Effective date

That would allow users to make their own modifications (assuming you trust them enough to add dataset name properly, anyway - or set up a stored proc to do the adding from a temp table that checked for conflicts) and allow you to handle format names that conflicted.  You'd still have to have a way for the user to handle using multiple datasets, if that's necessary (such as by adding some unique element to the format name by default, like 'dataset ID').

In my mind, however, the best option is using a data dictionary to handle the metadata, which combines self-documentation with metadata management.  Similar to above, you have a table with dataset and format elements, but add columns for descriptive text (question description, for example) and other useful information, depending on your use cases.  This can be maintained in a database table or dataset, or perhaps more usefully in an excel or similar document that can be shared with non-programmers and easily edited.  I use this method for several projects, and it has paid off by allowing my users to help write the documentation for my code, keeping my programs accurate and up to date, while minimizing back-and-forth discussions of updates.  I just import the spreadsheet and run a proc format each time I run my data.

You can then have one spreadsheet per dataset, one tab, or one full spreadsheet with all datasets in them - whichever is easiest to use.  This easily handles 'effective date' type issues as well - or even versioning, as that can be handled in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough input. The greatest risk is definitely controlling the consistency when maintaining all of the formats (in addition to staying up-to-date in general). I'm tempted to use plain old excel workbooks. They allow metadata (like effective dates), flexibility in processing through includes or macros, and all users in my situation are very familiar with excel. Initial decisions were leaning towards native SAS formats, but maybe those could be used for solely for `PICTURE` or other special SAS format needs, and all "normal" key-value formats could live in excel.